# JavaFX 'Main Thread' annotation

Tags: android, javafx, javafx-8

I am fairly new to JavaFX and am working on a multithreaded JavaFX 8 application. I have a callback and Observer design that needs to be handled on the main thread like so

```
public void someCallbackMethod() {
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

I was wondering if anybody wrote an annotation to handle this?

In Android development, through [Android Annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) project I am used to being able to use [@UIThread](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/96b773dbddb5205d1f974789d36bcc0e64710f07/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-api/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/annotations/UiThread.java) annotation to do

```
@UiThread    
public void someCallbackMethod() {

}
```

instead of

```
public void someCallbackMethod() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
}
```

Does something equivalent exist for JavaFX?

Comment: *In Android development, I am through the ...`@UiThread`(from support-annotations)* ... huh? ... this does nothing ... it just for lint hints(code inspection) ... nothing = will not add any code ... so you cannot use `code2` instead of `code3` ... with this annotation you just give a lint hint that it was **will be already called from UI thread**

Comment: ...anyway it should be possible with some AOP java annotations ... maybe aspectj ...

Comment: ..or ... call the callback with like: instead `code1` use `SubjectMethodImpl() {
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run()
        {
            observer.someCallbackMethod();
        }
    });
}` (and thats what @UiThread tells - that the method will be called like this)

Comment: You are right. I did not read the documentation of @UiThread properly and mistook it for something that it is not. Thx

Comment: Turns out I had my references wrong. I've edited my question.

Comment: If you are using Spring or AspectJ you might write an aspect for this as @Selvin suggested.
But as you are using Java8 you can abbreviate your sample to
`Platform.runLater(() ->{...});` using a lambda